# How to get Jfrog Xray scanArtifact result using API

Tags: jfrog-xray

I am doing a artifact scan using Xray post API

```
https://artifacts.org/xray/api/v1/scanArtifact
```

In response I get below

```
{
    "info": "Scan of artifact is in progress"
}
```

How do I get the result of this scan ,is there a API for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Since 3.42.3, there is a new method in the Xray's API called [Artifact Summary](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Xray+REST+API#XrayRESTAPI-ArtifactSummary)

Comment: However, I wasn't able to make it works. If anyone has a working request sample, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

You can use below api to get the Xray Scan result of am artifact :

```
https://artifacts-company.org/artifactory/ui/artifactxray?path=hello-world/v1/manifest.json&repoKey=my-local-repository
```

This returns below response :

```
{
    "xrayIndexStatus": "High",
    "xrayIndexStatusLastUpdatedTimestamp": "15-01-21 08:24:23 +00:00",
    "xrayBlocked": false,
    "xrayBlockReason": "",
    "detailsUrl": "https://artifacts-company.org/web/#/component/details/docker:~2F~2Fhello-world"
}
```

You can then use field xrayIndexStatus to get scan status as result.

Comment: Where can I find the value for repoKey ?

Comment: @CuriousLearner www.myartifactory.com/artifactory/api/repositories